# How should the nullable value of device_info_plus in the flutter package be handled?

Tags: flutter, uuid, flutter-packages

I used to use Flutter's **device_info** package, but recently decided to use the **device_info_plus** package because the code recommended the use of **device_info_plus**.

At first my code used identifierForVender and systemVersion of  IosDeviceInfo and both were **non-nullable values in the** **device_info** **package**, but when I changed to **device_info_plus package, both identifierForVender and systemVersion were nullable values**.

I use identifierForVender to uniquely identify the device and systemVersion to send the version of the app to the API request, and if both are nulled, I am in trouble because the bug occurs.

How is it correct to handle the above and nullable values?

Answer (score 0):

you can make it with the app opening,  i make it in splash screen init state and store data in shared preferences and when i need them i get them from shared preferences
i used bloc in my app

```
FutureOr<String?> getId({required String type}) async {
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
try {
  if (type == 'id') // get device id
  {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      //ios version
      IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      print('device id: ${iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor}');
      return SharedHelper().writeData(
          CachingKey.DEVICE_ID, iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor);
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      //android version
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      return SharedHelper()
          .writeData(CachingKey.DEVICE_ID, androidDeviceInfo.androidId);
    }
  } else if (type == 'device') // get device name
  {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      //ios version
      IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      return SharedHelper()
          .writeData(CachingKey.DEVICE_NAME, iosDeviceInfo.name);
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      //android version
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      return SharedHelper()
          .writeData(CachingKey.DEVICE_NAME, androidDeviceInfo.model);
    }
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
}
```

and this is init state

```
 void getDeviceInfo() async {
await SplashCubit.get(context).getId(type: 'id');
await SplashCubit.get(context).getId(type: 'device');
 }

void initState() {
getDeviceInfo();
super.initState();
}
```